# Почему тип не выводится автоматом?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename retType,class Func >
class Call
{
public:
    Call(Func* func)
    {
        func(500,500);
    };
};
```

Использование:

```
Call<int> call(Beep);//ошибка "слишком мало аргументов шаблона"
```

Почему тип func не может быть автоматов выведен?
С функциями так можно:

```
template<typename retType, class Func >
void fnc(Func* func)
{
    func(500, 500);
}
```

Использование:

```
fnc<int>(Beep);// все работает
```

Comment: с функциями так можно, потому что тип функции не "нарушается".  А тип шаблонный с одним параметром вы не определяли. Одному из параметров  можно присвоить тип по умолчанию, можно вообще убрать  первый параметр(ему там нечего делать).  И, вообще, если вы назвали параметр шаблона именем  Func, это еще не значит, что всегда  шаблон будет инстанцироваться типом функции, имеющий два аргумента целочисленного типа.  Шаблоны , написанные только для одного типа, теряю смысл, плюс могут  запутать в дальнейшем

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan я это для примера сделал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для шаблонов классов выводятся или все аргументы, или никакие.

Это обходится синтаксисом в духе `Call call(tag<int>{}, Beep);`, где `tag` - это

```
template <typename> struct tag {};
```

, а конструктор выглядит так:

```
Call(tag<retType>, Func* func)
```